# flash animation to ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, html

hallo i would like to convert this free flash animation ( with simple button)
http://luizfree.interfree.it/demoScrittori/demo.html
for ipad. i thought to convert this to html5 canvas but is too long. 
what could i do? ( convert all the scenes in quicktime ?)
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

well, sure exporting the flash to a quicktime may be the faster way, then you just need to cut it in many "scenes" to have multiple quickTime movie...

I heard that adobe is planning a flash exporter to html5... but you have to wait till... who know when...

Or you can try some html5 editor which allow easy animations,
the only one i've tried is "sencha animator", but you have to re-do all the animations...
Of course it has not all the options you can find in flash...

luca

ps
ma sei italiano, si?
sono tue le animazioni? quando si pptra' vedere la fine della storia?

Comment: I didn't know about Sencha Animator. Very nice looking tool. Thanks.

Comment: ciao si sono italiano, ma l animazione è di un mio amico . volevamo portare questi filmati su ipad, ma io ci sto combattendo come un pazzo perchè non riesco ad uscire vivo per la conversione in ipad, si sta dimostrando piu complicata del previsto ;))))

Comment: ma ti risulta qualche tecnica per ovviare a questi problemi?

Comment: no, mi spiace, il fatto e' che non sono veri "problemi", nel senso che tecnicamente con html5 o con object-c si puo' fare piu' o meno tutto quello che si puo' fare in flash, volendo... il vero problema e' che manca ancora un buon editor per le animazioni e va fatto tutto (o quasi) in programmazione, mentre in flash un buon grafico/animatore puo' essere autonomo per creare ottime animazioni. forse col tempo...